# How to create a jQuery loop to change anchor links based on JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, loops

I have a page which contains a select drop down, which contains country names, this then displays logos for brands based in that country.

However each of these brands have a country specific URL, which will need to change depending on the user selected country from the select.

The JSON file has the Brand Names that match the same names used for my data attribute.

Here is an idea of how the JSON structure is:

```
{
"US": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/" }
],
"Germany": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/de" },
    { "Brand": "Brand2", "Link": "http://www.example.com/germany" }
],
"France": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/france" },
    { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.com/fr" },
    { "Brand": "Brand4", "Link": "http://www.example.com/french-site" },
    { "Brand": "Brand5", "Link": "http://www.example.com/francais" }
],
"UK": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.net/" },
    { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.org" },
    { "Brand": "Brand6", "Link": "http://www.example.co.uk" }
]
}
```

How can I loop through my list of brand logos using jQuery, using the `data-brand-name` attribute in my markup, to change the anchor links based on what I have in my JSON file?

For example like:

> When user selects France from the select drop down, the brands belonging to French show up. I want the French links for these brands to be added into the anchor of the li tags.

Here is an example of my HTML:

```
<select name="select-choice" id="selectCountry">
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
</select>

<div class="brand-logo--wrapper container">
    <ul class="flex">
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand1 green-underline" data-brand-name="Brand1">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand2 green-underline" data-brand-name="Brand2">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand3 green-underline" data-brand-name="Brand3">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand4 green-underline" data-brand-name="Brand4">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand5" data-brand-name="Brand5">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="brand-logo-bg brand6" data-brand-name="Brand6">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any hard-coded, empty links that need to be looped over and configured. Just build the list items and the links dynamically based on looping over your object and then append the newly created items to the list.

See comments for further details:

```js
let myObj = {
  "US": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/" }
  ],
  "Germany": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/de" },
    { "Brand": "Brand2", "Link": "http://www.example.com/germany" }
  ],
  "France": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/france" },
    { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.com/fr" },
    { "Brand": "Brand4", "Link": "http://www.example.com/french-site" },
    { "Brand": "Brand5", "Link": "http://www.example.com/francais" }
  ],
  "UK": [
    { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.net/" },
    { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.org" },
    { "Brand": "Brand6", "Link": "http://www.example.co.uk" }
  ]
};


// Locate the correct DOM element to work with
let $list = $("ul.flex");

// Set up a change event handler on the select
$("#selectCountry").on("change", function(){

  $list.html("");                 // Clear out old list entries
  let country = $(this).val();    // Store the country name

  // Loop over all the corresponding links in the object
  $(myObj[country]).each(function(idx, item){
    // Conditionally set the green-underline class
    let gu = this.Brand.replace("Brand", "") > 4 ? "" : "green-underline";
    
    // Create a new bullet with hyperlink in it
    let $newItem = $('<li class="brand-logo-bg ' + item.Brand + ' ' + gu + ' ' + country + '" data-brand-name="' + item.Brand + '"><a href="' + item.Link + '" target="_blank">' + item.Brand + '</a></li>');

    // and append to list
    $list.append($newItem);
  });
  
});
```

```css
li { padding-bottom: 3px; }
.green-underline a { text-decoration:none; border-bottom:2px dashed green; }
.US { background-color:aliceblue; }
.Germany { background-color:lightgreen; }
.France { background-color:#f99; }
.UK { background-color:#ff9; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-choice" id="selectCountry">
    <option value="">--- Please Select Country ---</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
</select>

<div class="brand-logo--wrapper container">
        <ul class="flex"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I need the list items hardcoded as they contain the classes to show the background image for each brand. The list items will also have the country names they belong to as class names, so that they show/hide based on user selection. (unfortunately this wasn't done using an object in the first place, so have to continue with it for now)

Comment: @ImranR My solution is already adding the class names you showed in your post. Any other data can easily be added dynamically as well. I'll update the post to show this.

Comment: @ImranR Take a look at my updated answer. In particular, select France and look at the results, then right-click any of the hyperlinks and choose "Inspect". You will see that the right classes get added to the bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onchange` event listener to the select and pass the value of the selected option. The retrieve the value using the selected option from the json.

Instead of hardcoding the list in the html , create dynamic `li` while iterating the json

```js
let json = {
  "US": [{
    "Brand": "Brand1",
    "Link": "http://www.example.com/"
  }],
  "Germany": [{
      "Brand": "Brand1",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/de"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand2",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/germany"
    }
  ],
  "France": [{
      "Brand": "Brand1",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/france"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand3",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/fr"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand4",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/french-site"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand5",
      "Link": "http://www.example.com/francais"
    }
  ],
  "UK": [{
      "Brand": "Brand1",
      "Link": "http://www.example.net/"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand3",
      "Link": "http://www.example.org"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Brand6",
      "Link": "http://www.example.co.uk"
    }
  ]
}


function showBrand(val) {
  let brandList = '';
  json[val].forEach(function(item) {
    brandList += `<li class="brand-logo-bg brand1 green-underline" data-brand-name="${item.Brand}">
      <a href="" target="_blank">${item.Brand}</a>
    </li>`
  })
  document.getElementById('brands').innerHTML = brandList;
}
```

```html
<select name="select-choice" id="selectCountry" onchange='showBrand(this.value)'>
  <option value="" selected>Select</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
</select>

<div class="brand-logo--wrapper container">
  <ul class="flex" id='brands'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I need to do this using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

As solution, I first loop through the country keys and add them into the select with `append()`. Then when someone select one country, it update the list with their names and links that belong to the country.

```js
objs = {
  "US": [
      { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/" }
  ],
  "Germany": [
      { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/de" },
      { "Brand": "Brand2", "Link": "http://www.example.com/germany" }
  ],
  "France": [
      { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.com/france" },
      { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.com/fr" },
      { "Brand": "Brand4", "Link": "http://www.example.com/french-site" },
      { "Brand": "Brand5", "Link": "http://www.example.com/francais" }
  ],
  "UK": [
      { "Brand": "Brand1", "Link": "http://www.example.net/" },
      { "Brand": "Brand3", "Link": "http://www.example.org" },
      { "Brand": "Brand6", "Link": "http://www.example.co.uk" }
  ]
};

$.each(objs, function(country, brands){
  $("#selectCountry").append('<option value="' + country + '">' + country + '</option>');
});

$("#selectCountry").change(function(){
  let brands = objs[$("#selectCountry").val()];
  $.each(brands, function(key, brand){
    $("#myList").append('<li class="brand-logo-bg ' + brand.Brand.toLowerCase() + ' green-underline" data-brand-name="' + brand.Brand + '"><a href="' + brand.Link + '" target="_blank">' + brand.Brand + '</a></li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-choice" id="selectCountry">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<div class="brand-logo--wrapper container">
  <ul class="flex" id="myList"></ul>
</div>
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: Hello @ImranR, as I can see there is a lot of solution. My distinctively, dynamically use key for feeding the select, provide the anchor text and links, and use 100% jQuery. Moreover, I thought about `brand.Brand.toLowerCase()` in order to keep the same class name format. I hope it is fitting with your needs.